# Is it possible to select a pillar move based on problem facts in timefold?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

Is it possible to select entities of a PillarMove based on other properties of the entity than PlanningVariables. For example my Entity has a PlanningVariable startTime and a type that is a ProblemFact. I want so select a pillar based on the startTime and all Entities that have the same value in their type property. Is that possible? I can't see that feature in the docs https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#pillarMoveSelectors but I think its very essential.
Is the only way to implement a custom move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not think of a way of doing that.

You could perhaps write your own [custom move](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#customMoves) that would be inspired by our pillar move. But it is definitely not easy and it takes you outside of the public API, so it carries risks.

Comment: This would be a good case for Move Streams one day.